# Odd error in C involving Labels, Statements, and Declarations, Code Cleanup

Tags: c, sorting, file-io, declaration

I'm writing a program that will read in a given text file, display a menu with options to sort the file (a list of names) using either C or Perl. and output the sorted list to a new file designated by the user.  I'm running into an odd error after the FILE label on line 38 and 60.  I put the ' ;' after it because I read something saying a Label can only be followed by a statement, so inserting a blank statement should resolve the issue.  Before I put the ' ;' in I was getting these errors:

> Struct.c: In function ‘main’:
>   Struct.c:38:17: error: a label can only be part of a statement and a declaration is not a statement
>   Struct.c:40:17: error: expected expression before ‘char’
>   Struct.c:44:30: error: ‘line’ undeclared (first use in this function)
>   Struct.c:44:30: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
>   Struct.c:48:17: warning: passing argument 4 of ‘qsort’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by   default]
>   /usr/include/stdlib.h:761:13: note: expected ‘__compar_fn_t’ but argument is of type ‘int (*)(const char *, const char *)’
>   Struct.c:60:17: error: a label can only be part of a statement and a declaration is not a statement

After I put the ' ;' in, I was receiving these errors:

> Struct.c: In function ‘main’:
>   Struct.c:38:17: error: a label can only be part of a statement and a declaration is not a statement
>   Struct.c:48:17: warning: passing argument 4 of ‘qsort’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
>   /usr/include/stdlib.h:761:13: note: expected ‘__compar_fn_t’ but argument is of type ‘int (*)(const char *, const char *)’
>   Struct.c:60:17: error: a label can only be part of a statement and a declaration is not a statement

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <string.h>

FILE *popen(const char *command, const char *mode);
int pclose(FILE *stream);

int main(void) {
    char strIn[128], *p;
    printf("Enter a source filename: ");
    fgets(strIn, sizeof strIn, stdin);
    p = strchr(strIn, '\n');
    if (p != NULL) *p = '\0';
    printf("You entered: %s \n", strIn);

    char strOut[128], *q;
    printf("Enter a destination filename: ");
    fgets(strOut, sizeof strOut, stdin);
    p = strchr(strOut, '\n');
    if (q != NULL) *q = '\0';
    printf("You entered: %s \n", strOut);  

    while (1){
        int sel;
        printf("MENU\n");
        printf("=====\n");
        printf("1. Sort Using C code\n");
        printf("2. Sort Using Perl\n");
        printf("3. Search for a Word Using Perl\n");
        printf("4. Exit\n");
        printf("=====\n");
        printf("Enter selection: ");
        sel = getchar();
        sel = sel-48;
        switch(sel){
            case 1:
                FILE * inFile, * outFile;
                 ;
                char line[25];
                char lines[60][25];
                int i, items = 0;
                inFile = fopen(strIn, "r");
                while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), inFile)){
                    strcpy(lines[items], line);
                    items++;
                }
                qsort(lines, items, 25, strcmp);

                outFile = fopen(strOut, "w");
                for (i=0; i<items; i++) {
                    fputs(lines[i], outFile);
                }

                fclose(inFile);
                fclose(outFile);
                break;

            case 2:
                FILE *cmd;

                snprintf(strOut, sizeof strOut, "perl -e 'print sort <>' %s", strIn);
                cmd = popen(strOut, "r");
                if (cmd == NULL) {
                    perror("popen");
                    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                }
                while (fgets(strOut, sizeof(strOut), cmd)) {
                    printf("%s", strOut);
                }
                pclose(cmd);

                break;
            case 3:
                //Find a Word and Return line Number using Perl
                break;
            case 4:
                exit(0);
            case -38:
                printf("Code is reading in LineFeed and displaying Menu again\n");
                break;
            default:
                printf("Error: Input was not a valid selection.\n");
                break;
        }
    }
return 0;
}
```

What's going on with all these errors? I'm also not sure why qsort wouldn't be working.

Thanks,

EDIT: I moved the two FILE labels directly above the while loop, this solves the Label-Statement issue, but the program still doesn't behave as it should.  The two printfs that say "You entered: " don't print out and it immediately exits? right after I type in the destination file and hit enter.

Comment: I've rolled back your latest edit. You modified the code to correct the problem you're asking about. Please don't do that; it makes the question useless.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer is that you cannot declare variables as the first line inside of a switch statement's case statement (which, at it's heart, is just a label);

You can declare them inside of the case statement, they just cannot directly follow the label.

The same is true if you try to place a label anywhere in the program.  Try adding "IM_A_LABEL:" at the first line of main().  You'll get the same error there

**EDIT:**

You mentioned in a comment that your program was crashing somewhere along the way, after entering the second filename.  I built your code and ran it through gdb, and you're crashing at the line

```
if (q != NULL) *q = '\0';
```

This makes sense, because you declare q like so:

```
char strOut[128], *q;
```

q is just a pointer, not pointing at any actual space.  You need to malloc space for this pointer.

You don't do anything with q aside from that check, so I removed it.  Following that, your program went through your menu loop correctly.  I didn't try to test the logic because I don't have your input file, but I selected exit, and I indeed exited without crashing.

This is a good example of why pointers should be initialized to NULL at declaration.  You check for NULL before attempting to dereference it, but it doesn't matter, because you have some garbage, non-NULL value in there from the declaration.  I commented that line out because you don't use it, but you could have just as easily left the line in, and changed your declaration to

```
char strIn[128], *q = NULL;
```

This will allow your proper check for to actually work.  Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: I moved both labels to here:
        sel = getchar();
        sel = sel-48;
        FILE * inFile, * outFile;
        FILE *cmd;

Right above the switch statement.  For some reason this causes my program to exit/crash right after typing in the destination filename.  Could the labels be causing this?

Comment: The "FILE *inFile, *outFILE" and "FILE *cmd" are the only things that need to be moved outside of the case statement.  I'm having a hard time picturing how the other changes look; can you edit your posted code to reflect these changes?

Comment: Sorry, didn't think of that.  Code is edited in the main post.

Comment: Sorry, when I mentioned editing above, I meant editing the post in general to add any changes you've made to your code (not editing the code itself).  No big deal, just makes it easier to track down problems when code changes.  Now, where exactly is your program terminating?  Does it exit, or do you segfault?  By the way, you're still declaring things inside of the switch block.  It only compiles because your lonely semicolon counts as an empty statement

Comment: I moved the two FILE labels directly above the while loop. I've been playing around, trying to debug it and it never even prints the two file names.
These are the only two lines that appear once I run it:
Enter a source filename: data.txt
Enter a destination filename: output2.txt
Then it just exits? and the command prompt displays again.

Comment: You're amazing.  This does indeed fix the crashing bit. Wish I could upvote your response more.

Answer (score 3):

As of the 1990 C standard, declarations and statement may not be mixed within a block. All declarations must appear first, followed by all statements. A "block", or *compound statement*, is delimited by opening and closing braces `{` ... `}`.

The 1999 standard relaxed this rule, permitting declarations and statements to be mixed within a block -- but a label (either `case expr:` or `label_name:`) can only be applied to a statement.

Since you have mixed declarations and statements before the `case` statement, and you didn't mention any error messages for those, I'll assume you're compiling in C99 or C11 mode (or at least using a compiler that permits mixed declarations and statements as an extension on top of C90).

So if you have this:

```
    switch(sel){
        case 1:
            FILE * inFile, * outFile;
            char line[25];
```

then the case label applies to the *declaration* `FILE * inFile, * outFile;`, which is illegal (a syntax error) in C90, C99, and C11.

The cleanest solution is to introduce a new block, so that the declaration is at the beginning of that block:

```
    switch(sel){
        case 1:
            {
                FILE * inFile, * outFile;
                char line[25];
                /* more code here */
                break;
            }
        case 2:
            /* etc. */
    }
```

This also has the advantage that it limits the scope of `inFile` and `outFile` to that block; otherwise those identifiers remain visible up to the end of the *enclosing* block, which extends to the end of the `case` statement.

(An ugly solution is to insert a null statement (just a semicolon) immediately after the `case 1:`.  That will make the compiler happy, but it's counterintuitive and it doesn't limit the scope of the declarations.)

Answer (score 0):

You're declaring variables inside a switch block, which is illegal. Move you declarations before you switch block.

Comment: This isn't 100% correct; they can exist inside of the case block, just not directly following the case statement

Comment: @DonShankin: You mean not directly following the `case` *label*.